# Magento adding left column in home page

Tags: php, html, magento

In my magento project left side of the Home page is empty, i want to place an image in left side and also in the middle portion, what are the steps to place these two in my project?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Magento directory under /app/design/frontend/default/(your current theme -- or default)/template/page/html, you'll find your global basics for things like your header, footer, breadcrumb trail, etc.  If you want to add text/images throughout your site, that's the place to look first.

If you're looking to add text/images *only* to your home page, you can use the CMS features in the admin.

Also, the Magento site has a pretty clear tutorial on how to manage your site design and templates:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/how-magento-builds-content